# Angular number directive not working on some devices

Tags: angular

I wrote a directive for my number inputs in my Angular 10 app. With this directive, I am preventing **+ - e . [dot]** characters and allowing only **0-9 numbers** and **, [comma]** for decimal numbers like prices.

But I have a problem. At some devices, directive works properly and allows only to comma, however at some devices directive prevents both comma and dot and user can't write a decimal number.

I've compared those devices for like language, seperator, keyboard options, etc. They are exactly the same. I don't know what is causing this.

[Playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular10-directives-hshkwv?file=src/app/app.component.html)

**directive.ts:**

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'input[numbersOnly]',
})
export class NumberOnlyDirective {
  constructor() {}

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: any) {
    const charCode = event.key;
    
    if (charCode == "-" || charCode == "+" || charCode == "e" || charCode == ".") {
      return false;
    }

    if (event.shiftKey && charCode == "+") {
        return false;
    }

    if ((event.ctrlKey && charCode == "v") || (event.ctrlKey && event.shiftKey && charCode == "V") || (event.shiftKey && charCode == "Insert")) {
        let val: string = event.target.value;
        val = val.toLocaleLowerCase("tr-TR");

        if (val.includes("e") || val.includes("+") || (!val.startsWith("-") && val.includes("-"))) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an explicit example or test case that fails? Like any specific kind of device? What is your precise error. Some expected and actual Input Output pairs could be helpful

Comment: @Chund I've added a playground. Written value should not include specified characters above. I should write 150 or 150,65 but not -150 or 150.56 etc.